# Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, undefined

I have looked but it seems I can't find the right answer or I don't have the skills for that. The thing is I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: node in include() (line 69 of /home/xwebmedia/public_html/ltr/sites/all/themes/ltr/page.tpl.php).
```

and the code I'm using is:

```
<?php
if (count($node->field_adds) != 0)
{
    foreach($node->field_adds['und'] as $key => $value)
    {               
        $nid = $value['nid']; 
        $mywidget = node_view(node_load($nid));
        print drupal_render($mywidget);
    }       
}
?>
```

Thing is everything is working fine, I get my widgets with adds in sidebar, but I am having this notice of error.

I know that I need to define a variable in `template.php` but I tried something it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Check that $node has been set.

```
<?php
if (isset($node) && count($node->field_adds) != 0)
{
    foreach($node->field_adds['und'] as $key => $value)
    {               
        $nid = $value['nid']; 
        $mywidget = node_view(node_load($nid));
        print drupal_render($mywidget);
    }       
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The page template file doesn't have a `$node` variable by default (you can have pages that aren't nodes so it's not required).

The [`menu_get_object()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function is your friend here:

```
$node = menu_get_object();
if ($node) {
  ...
}
```